# How to convert Date and time into epoch in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp, unix-timestamp, epoch

I have a google sheet where i have a column date and time in the following format

```
14-08-2021 12:30:00
```

I want a result in Epoch which is in this format 1591259160

i tried this code in script editor but i am not getting result

```
    function convertDates(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range_input = sheet.getRange(1, 1);

  range_input = range_input.getValue();
  range_input = range_input.replace("at ", " ");
  sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(range_input);
}
```

How to get desired result in google sheet

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`new Date(range_input.getValue()).valueOf();`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I have used following formula

```
=(DATEVALUE(date_cell)-(70*365)-19)*86400+time_in_seconds
```

A bit of explaination. Google for some reason presents [datevalue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252) as index starting (basically 'days since') 1900-01-01, thus in order to get unix epoch time which is seconds since 1970-01-01 you have to **add 70 years** (70*365), **multiply by seconds in day** (*86400) and **add time converted to seconds** (+time_in_seconds). Only the **-19** part baffles me, I haven't put much thoughut into it but those may have something to do with leap years.
Once you have your epochtime I encourage to [doublecheck it](https://www.epochconverter.com/).